# How to combine bootstrap paginator and select to filter a table?

Tags: python, django, paginator

I currently use paginator on a table. I want to add a select to filter the table but I do not manage how to navigate through pages without loosing my selection.

Currently (see code below) when I navigate by clicking on previous or next, option selected by used is lost and all data are presented.

I must change the 'else' condition to take account the option selected. I was thinking about using global variable to store option selected in a variable but it can have side-effect and it is not so recommended...

views.py

```py
@login_required
def index(request):

    # data sent (click on 'search' button or option selected)
    if request.POST:
        # data from select
        selection = request.POST.get('selection', False)
        # data from search
        ide = request.POST.get('ide', False)

        # search
        if ide == "":
            paginator = Paginator(Preinclusion.objects.all(), 5)
            preincluded = paginator.page(1)
        else:
            paginator = Paginator(Preinclusion.objects.filter(pat_num__startswith = ide),5)
            preincluded = paginator.page(1)

        # select
        if selection == 'Randomized':
            print('Randomized')
            paginator = Paginator([patient for patient in Preinclusion.objects.all() if patient.is_randomized], 5)
            preincluded = paginator.page(1)

        elif selection == 'Not randomized':
            print('Not randomized')
            paginator = Paginator([patient for patient in Preinclusion.objects.all() if not patient.is_randomized], 5)
            preincluded = paginator.page(1)

        elif selection == 'All patients':
            print('All patients')
            paginator = Paginator(Preinclusion.objects.all(), 5)
            preincluded = paginator.page(1)

        if not preincluded:
            liste_existe = False # non utilisé dans le template

    else:

        # first index visited
        paginator = Paginator(Preinclusion.objects.all(), 5)
        page = request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            preincluded = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            preincluded = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            preincluded = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'randomization/index.html', {'preincluded': preincluded})
```

I would like to `store` selected option for previous/next navigation.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Django session to store whatever you want, example: `request.session['my_key'] = 'My Value'`

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your 'selection' attribute to a render context like this

```
    return render(request, 'randomization/index.html', {'preincluded': preincluded, 'selection': selection})
```

Then, process this context variable in template ({{ selection }}), and set selected option by this value. One of possible variants will be just like this:

```
<select>
<option value="Randomized" {% if selection == "Randomized" %}selected{% endif %}>1</option>
</select>
```

As you said, avoid to use global variables in asynchronous and stateless applications

Comment: thanks to both for replying ! for the moment I am lost, too many if/else conditions... it sould be simpliest but I am not good in algo

Comment: Don't afraid of using conditions in template, it's the one of a few things for what they are built